# Checking Empty return in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was thinking about this code when validation in javascript

```
resp = {empty}; //empty from some type of data like (array,string,object)
if (resp === '' || resp === ' ' || resp === null || ect{checking another type data})
```

It seem funny to look at, it should be simple in one function empty ex.

```
if (empty(resp)) // do something
```

When I  looked it up in the MDN documentation there is an [`empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty) function , but the behaviour is not like I mentioned before.
I think javascript should have a core function for checking return value like (empty string, object,array,ect) .

What's your opinion ?

Comment: Define "empty". Why is a string containing one space character "empty"? Why can you have so many possible return values that you need to check?

Comment: Firstly, you're confusing MSDN with MDN. Those are two entirely different resources. Secondly, empty in the context of the article does not pertain to a string/object. This is referencing an empty statement. From the article you linked (MDN): "The empty statement is a semicolon (;) indicating that no statement will be executed." That has nothing to do with strings/objects.

Comment: Empty can mean many things depending on the context - blank strings, empty arrays, empty statements such as `;` or even falsey values.

Comment: @deceze because `' '`,`null` and `''` is different , this usage when validation input.

Comment: @jacob what i need here is not empty function name , but something function to checking inside value variable is empty or not.about MSDN i am missing typo the right is MDN

Comment: @viyancs, So, am I to interpret that empty in this case is to check for empty strings, or empty arrays, or empty what? Please be more specific.

Comment: @lfender6445 yeah i mean like that , empy string, array,object , or everything of that has been available inside variable.

Comment: There shouldn't be one unified function which checks for *all of these cases!* What about *two* spaces `'  '`? What about *three*? What about `0`? What about `'0'`? If you are validating input, then you need to write your own rules. Your input should not return `null` either, it's probably always going to be a string; so `str.trim().length > 0` would probably the check you're looking for. `null` would be/should be a very different case you need to handle separately.

Comment: @deceze, You could write a function that would handle all of those concerns, but from a readability, maintainability standpoint, it shouldn't be done. 

You're probably better off abstracting empty checks into their own areas. Empty checks for each expected type will be more maintainable at the end of the day.

Comment: @deceze okay this is the problem i think your suggestion is what should we do in our script , and that will be possible to complex rule and code, so why there are no function like `empty` in php maybe ?

Comment: FYI: `empty($var)` in PHP is exactly the same as `$var == false`, only additionally it won't throw an error if `$var` does not exist! In PHP's type system many different values are *falsey*. But even `' '` is *not* *falsey*. In Javascript's type system not as many values are *falsey*. Arguably, Javascript's type system is a bit saner than PHP's (not by much, but a bit). There are a ton of pitfalls in PHP with accidentally equating values to `false` which you need to be aware of. **It's actually often _not_ a good thing to throw too many things into the same pot!**

Comment: @deceze i know that , like you said is not similar with empty in php, i think is really helpfull  if there are function to checking like i said, but this is just my opinion because it's possible developer create something rule for checking empty array, object, string ,ect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are working with a value that is assumed to be a string

```
String.prototype.empty = function(){
     return (this.length <= 0 || this == '');
}
console.log(''.empty());
```

I did not handle undefined or null because that could cause an issue if its purposely set to those values. The prototype will only work on string objects.

Empty is not cross-browser compatible on many platforms, i would recommend staying away from using it.

Comment: thanks for answer rixhard, maybe in this question just 2 possible answer first we create our rule ofr validation second javascript create that for us ..

Comment: Yes, the prototype will not work if the string is not a string; So, you will not have to validate the typeof object.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, when do you need this? The only time something like this would be useful is if your variable could possibly hold a string, or an array, or an object, or `null`, or whatever. If you're ever in a situation where one variable can possibly hold this many different types, you're doing something every wrong!*

If you want to check user input, that input is going to be a string. If you have a variable which is supposed to hold user input and it's not a string, then what are you doing? OK, so maybe the variable could hold `null` or a string, where `null` would represent that the user didn't input anything, for example by cancelling the input dialog. Well, isn't that a case which you would want to handle separately anyway?

Variables may have different types to enable you to distinguish between different cases. `null` has a different meaning (e.g. action canceled) than an empty string (successful input, but empty) than a boolean `false` (something went wrong). You shouldn't have that many possible types in one variable in the first place, but if you do, you should probably treat them all differently.

And if you legitimately happen to be in a situation where you *can* handle them all equally... well, most of them equate to `false` to begin with; and the ones that don't you just have to check yourself.

And `' '` should never, ever, in any language be treated as "empty". It's a string with content. If you regard this content as not worthy, write your own check.

It usually pays off if you're strict about types. You should expect a variable to be of one or a very small handful of defined types, and treat it as such. If you expect the variable to be a string, write your check as `str.trim().length == 0`. This code will fail with an error if `str` is not actually a string. And that's good. Because that means your program actually produced a value you weren't expecting, which points to a bug. Too generalised functions like `empty` are just good at plastering over and hiding such problems, when actually they should produce *visible errors* as early as possible.

<sub>* Hey, if you're writing a JSON encoder or such, you know what you're doing, and you know that you need to treat each type on its own anyway. I don't mean you.</sub>

Comment: thaks for the answer,

i believe or not i am use this function maybe any 3 or 5 and i create my own validation , when the reposne from array, object, or string, i am not mad in this but i can smile , hehehe

maybe better i create my rule to handle this then when i need that function separatelly i can fix by call it. then i don't know someone that have same case.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

`if(typeof(resp) != "undefined" && resp !== null) {`..`}`

This will be true if the variable is defined and not null.

Comment: This doesn't check for many conditions that @viyancs is asking about - although his question isn't accurate. Empty is more than null, undefined, falsey values, etc. It could be an empty string, an empty array, or some other condition.